# View for displaying nounal and verbal pages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, haml

I've got this code in my View that just list two type of links.

Here's an example output:

**Nounal Pages**

- cleaners/house-cleaners

**Verbal Pages**

- cleaning/house-cleaning

Here's the view code. How could this be refactored to remove duplicate and push logic and loops out of the view?

```
  %h3 Nounal Pages
  %ul.row-fluid
  - categories.each do |category|
    - subcategories.each do |subcategory|
      %ul
        %li= link_to "#{category.pluralised_nounal_slug}/#{subcategory.pluralised_nounal_slug}", main_app.new_pluralised_nounal_subcategory_path(category: category.pluralised_nounal_slug, subcategory: subcategory.pluralised_nounal_slug), target: '_blank'

  %h3 Verbal Pages
  %ul
  - categories.each do |category|
    - subcategories.each do |subcategory|
      - if category.verbal_slug.present? && subcategory.verbal_slug.present?
        %ul
          %li= link_to "#{category.verbal_slug}/#{subcategory.verbal_slug}", main_app.new_verbal_subcategory_path(category: category.verbal_slug, subcategory: subcategory.verbal_slug, aspect: 'verbal'), target: '_blank'
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider having the controller (or some other thing that is not the view) set up all of the data, such that the view can merely do this:

```
- @nounals.each do |text, uri|
  %ul
    %li= link_to text, uri, target: '_blank'
```

and

```
- @verbals.each do |text, uri|
  %ul
    %li= link_to text, uri, target: '_blank'
```

Once the two loops are the same other than the variable, you can use a partial template to render each of them.